How do I call variables within a JSON in Microsoft Copilot Studio?
Within the following JSON, I want to place variables to store titles or categories in Copilot Studio. What is the process to be able to take the variables within the JSON?
What is the way to call variables from Copilot Studio to this JSON?
{ "input": [ { "_users_id_requester": "657", "content": "NOSE", "itilcategories_id": "135", "name": "NOSE", "type": "1" } ] }
enter image description here
I'm trying to figure out how to declare variables within a JSON. My expectation is to be able to call those variables within the JSON.

What do you mean by "vairables within a JSON"?

I had the same problem trying to add variables in a Post HTTP call,  and the solution I found here: https://community.powerplatform.com/forums/thread/details/?threadid=f5c1dd84-0a10-41e5-a28b-5427e9b04bb7
I was trying to send some variables that I get from an adapative card, and pass in a service as a json.  And the solution was to put as a json without quotes and instead of select Edit JSON i select Edit formula and it works!
this is a sample as it works for me

